# NTFS read only driver

Tags: kernel, ntfs

I am trying to develop ntfs read only driver for Android. But I dont understand how do I create a superblock required by VFS from $MFT. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the open source ntfs-3g project, it provides a good reference for NTFS internals.